# android: gridview cells are not equally aligned horizontally

Tags: android, gridview

i am building a game that its board is based on grid view.
I have a grid view with diffrent kinds of layouts. each layout is an image view ( a dot, horizontal and vertical lines and a blank image view ) but with diffrent width and heights.

**the problem: for some reason, there is a space between columns ( even if I set horizontalSpacing to 0 ), and not an equal space between all of them.**

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:numColumns="5"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
       />
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please share the xml code for individual item.

Comment: `<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    />`

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that the gravity was set to "start" by defult.

`android:gravity="center_horizontal"`

this line in the gridview fixed the problem